# How to set font strikethrought in PowerPoint, Office 365?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I run PowerPoint in Office 365.

How to set font StrikeThrough in PowerPoint with C#?
StrikeThrough doesn´t exist under PowerPoint Cell, TextFrame, TextRange and Font (StrikeThrough exist for Word and Excel).

Here is my code and I want t to add StrikeThrough as well in PowerPoint:

```
for (int r = 0; r < powerpointTable.Table.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < powerpointTable.Table.Columns.Count; c++)
    {
         string cellData = "XXX";                            
         PowerPoint.Cell cell = powerpointTable.Table.Cell(r + 1, c + 1);
         PowerPoint.TextFrame txFrm = cell.Shape.TextFrame;
         PowerPoint.TextRange range = txFrm.TextRange;
         range.Font.Color.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Black);
         range.Font.Bold = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
         range.Font.Italic = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
         range.Font.Underline = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
         range.Text = cellData;
    }

}
```

powerpointTable is my table I PowerPoint and I using

```
PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
```

Comment: Apparently you have to use `TextRange2` instead: [Strikethrough in PowerPoint vba](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?61062-Strikethrough-in-PowerPoint-vba). I can't verify that right now, but if it does work then you can answer your own question.

Comment: Thanks!                                                                                               TextRange2 dosen't exist in C# but TextFrame2 do, so it's possible to write this code in C#:                                                
                                                                                 powerpointTable.Table.Cell(r + 1, c + 1).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.StrikeThrough = MsoTriState.msoTrue;